# ssh connection hopping with different users

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I have 3 computers **A**, **B** and **C**, where there is no direct connection between A and C.

I need an access to the computer **C** from the computer **A**.

The computer **C** is behind a firewall and can only reverse tunnel on the computer **B**.

**A** has access to **B** with a specific user, and **B** can only access to another user on **C**.

I wanted to know if there is a way to connect **A** to **C** through **B** with this configuration. (It would be even better without using a configuration file)

The command used by **C** to reverse tunnel on **B** is (this is not the problem, it works well):

```
ssh -v -N -R 2222:localhost:9876 IP_OF_B
```

I saw that I needed to do a connection hopping with something like this (from **A**):

```
ssh -W ACCOUNT_ON_C@localhost:2222 USER_ON_B@IP_OF_B
```

But when I do this, I get an error : `channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`

By the way, all of the 3 computers run linux.

Comment: did you try to put all the information into `ssh_config`? It looks like a real mess from this point of view. In config you can specify and see all the options in one place.

Comment: I can set the configuration for B in my ssh_config, but the configuration for C changes everytime, so I cannot really do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's wrong with .. ?

```
ssh -t -l userB B ssh -l userC C
```

where

- userX is user on host X
- `-t` force tty allocation.

Comment: this method will not allow authentication using local keys.

Comment: Hum, there is nothing wrong with this, that's exactly what I wanted to do ! Thanks !

Comment: @Jakuje what error are you having ?